# Añadir un conjunto de caracteres similares dentro de una etiqueta con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, string

**Saludos**, Me gustaría agregar un conjunto de caracteres similares dentro de una etiqueta `<b></b>` de una cadena con Jquery.

La pregunta es, si hay una manera mas simple de obtener ese resultado. ya que yo utilizo muchos condicionantes y creo que habrá otra forma mas fácil de hacerlo.
Este es mi codigo `Html` :

```
<p>Lorem---- Ipsum is --------- simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ---- industry---.</p>
<h4>Resultado</h4>
<p id='result'></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>b{color:red}</style>
```

Este es mi codigo `jQuery` :

```
var textC=$("p").html();
textC=textC.split(''); //Separo los caracteres

//Recorre caracter por caracter
for(var i=0; i< textC.length; i++){
//Comprueba
  if(textC[i] == '-'){
    if(textC[i]!=textC[i-1]){
      textC[i-1] = textC[i-1]+'<b>-' //Agrega inicio de etiqueta
    }
    if(textC[i]!=textC[i+1]){
      textC[i] = '-</b>'//Agrega fin de etiqueta
    }
   
  } 
  
}
console.log(textC.join())
$('#result').html(textC.join('')) //Une los caracteres y muestra el resultado
```

El resultado seria algo asi

```
<p id='result'>Lorem<b>----</b> Ipsum is <b>---------</b> simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting <b>----</b> industry<b>---</b>.</p>
```

Comment: Puedes usar un map en vez del for pero el resultado seria el mismo

Comment: Esto agrega un guión de más: `textC[i] = '-</b>'` ... cámbialo por `textC[i] = '</b>'`

Comment: @HernánGarcia gracias por recomendar lo intentare utilizando un **map**

Comment: De hecho tendrian que ser así:  `textC[i-1] += '<b>' //Agrega inicio de etiqueta` y `textC[i] += '</b>'//Agrega fin de etiqueta`

Comment: Gracias por comentar @masterguru eso fue intencional, porque no quiero que pierda caracteres aunque podría ser textC[i] = textC[i]+ '</b>', pero sigo buscando un código mas simple.

Comment: `textC[i] = textC[i]+ '</b>'` y  `textC[i] += '</b>'` es lo mismo, y reduces el código

Comment: @masterguru gracias eso no lo sabia.

Comment: Aqui lo tienes con un switch... no reduce el código demasiado, pero quita condicionales **if**:  https://jsfiddle.net/oy6r38tk/

Comment: @masterguru Eso se ve mejor al mi código, Gracias 